Can not set the state value to the api response
I am building a basic context where I getting a response from an api that i build, simple one no auth and headers. Yet when I am trying to set the state value of the api response data the state value seems to be empty i.e. the default value of the useState hook;

Following is the api response;
[{
"id": "C8144412-E7BE-4CC4-BB0A-294938E38BD6",
    "appName": "some App",
    "p1AlertCount": 1,
    "p2AlertCount": 2,
    "appScore": 20,
    "appStatus": true,
    "message": "up and running"}, 
...
]

the below is the context api code;
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AppStatus from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

const AppContext = createContext<AppStatus[] | null>(null);

const api_endpoint: string = `http://localhost:5289/AppStatus`;

const AppProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<AppStatus[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async (url: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const appData: AppStatus[] = (await response.data) as AppStatus[];

      if (response.status != 200 || response.statusText != "OK") {
        throw new Error("failed to fetch");
      }

      setLoading(false);
      setFetchedData(appData);
      console.log(appData);
      console.log(fetchedData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`error is ${error}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(api_endpoint);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, fetchedData }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider, useGlobalContext };


response type set in the react proj;
export default interface AppStatus {
  id: string;
  appName: string;
  p1AlertCount: number;
  p2AlertCount: number;
  appScore: number;
  appStatus: boolean;
  message: string;
}

API model;
namespace App_Health_Mock_API.Model
{
    public class AppDataModel
    {
        public required string Id { get; set; }
        public required string AppName { get; set; }
        public required int P1AlertCount { get; set; } = 0;
        public required int P2AlertCount { get; set; } = 0;
        public required int AppScore { get;set; }
        public required Boolean AppStatus { get; set; } = true;
        public required string Message { get; set; }
    }
}

I need help on how to set the value of my state value i.e. fetchedData to the appData(axios response.data)
I tried to type safe the response data and the state value as much as I could, loged the response data to double check if I am getting the correct array, and I am getting it. Only expectation is to set the value of the "fetchedData" to the appData value.

Try removing <AppStatus[]> temporarily from your setFetchedData state setter. It's looks to me like it's expecting a boolean ...

Anyone getting to this question, the answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately  , but the catch is if you add the fetchedData in the dependency array it will cause the useState to update repeatedly, instead used isLoading, which mitigated the issue.

You made mistake for returned values in typings for the context and you don't need to await the response.data you already get a response with await axios.get. Using of try/catch block is enough and you don't need to check for response.status and response.statusText.
Modified example:
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AppStatus from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

interface IAppContext {
  isLoading: boolean;
  fetchedData: AppStatus[];
}

const AppContext = createContext<Partial<IAppContext>>({});

const AppProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<AppStatus[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<AppStatus[]>(
          'http://localhost:5289/AppStatus'
        );

        setLoading(false);
        setFetchedData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, fetchedData }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider, useGlobalContext };

